# Does the Serilog console sink support expressions?

Tags: c#, serilog, serilog-expressions

I'm trying to output to console by configuring the sink as follows:

```
{
  "Name": "Console",
  "Args": {
    "theme": "Serilog.Sinks.SystemConsole.Themes.AnsiConsoleTheme::Code, Serilog.Sinks.Console",
    "Formatter": {
      "Type": "Serilog.Templates.ExpressionTemplate, Serilog.Expressions",
      "Template": "{@t:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff} [{@l:u3}] [{#if SourceContext is not null}{Substring(SourceContext, LastIndexOf(SourceContext, '.') + 1)}{#end}{#if MemberName is not null}.{MemberName}{#end}] {@m:lj}\n{@x}"
    }
  }
}
```

But it's not working. Does this sink not support expression templates?

Comment: https://github.com/serilog/serilog-expressions shows how to do it without the config wiring - I'd validate my expressions in a testbed and then solve how to wire an ExpressionTemplate after that (have not used expressions or config, but they are orthogonal, and I dont want to see you blocked)

Comment: @RubenBartelink If I do it in code like `WriteTo.Console(new ExpressionTemplate(...))` with the template above it works fine. But I want to configure the console sink in appsettings.

Comment: OK then the answer to your question "Does the Console Sink support expressions" is YES. The simplified question is "How to wire Serilog Settings parsing to a Console log with an ExpressionTemplate", and you can show the code that works, and the settings layout you are trying. Hopefully someone that understands how the settings binding works can step in